# $p^{2}$-th power residue and $p^{th}$ power residue

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $a$ be an integer and $p, p^{\prime}$ be two distinct primes not dividing $a$ and $m$ be a natural number.

I was trying to prove/disprove that : If $a^{p^{m-1}}$ is a $p^{m}$-th power residue modulo $p^{\prime}$, then $a$ is a $p^{th}$ power modulo $p^{\prime}$.

I think the restriction that $p$ and $p^{\prime}$ do not divide $a$ is necessary. Otherwise, using the fact that $16 = 2^{2^{2}}$ is always an $8 = 2^{3}-\mathrm{th}$ power modulo almost every prime, we can reach the conclusion that $2$ is a quadratic residue modulo almost every prime. This is absurd, since $2$ is quadratic residue modulo $p$ only when $p \equiv \pm 1 (\hspace{1mm} \text{mod } 8)$.

I was convinced that this must surely be false; but working on some examples that could be calculated by hand -- now I am convinced otherwise. In short, I am confused now. I would be so grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1):

If $p$ doesn't divide $p'-1$ it's obviously correct, because every number is a p-th residue then, otherwise it's wrong. For example, look at $a=3, p=2, p'=5, m=3$: $a^4 \equiv 1 \pmod 5$, which is obviously an 8-th power residue, but $3$ isn't a quadratic residue mod $5$